# Is there any keyword like "Only IN" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need something like -

```
Select * from RoomMemberTable where RoomMemberId "ONLY IN" ('RM1','RM3')
```

My table structure -

```
RoomId  RoomMemberId
R1       RM1
R1       RM2
R1       RM3
R2       Rm1
R2       RM2
R3       RM1
R3       RM3
```

I need to get rows which contain only these room members. I don't need entries where any other member except RM1 and RM3 are present.

Comment: In your example you only want room R3? As a single row `R3` or two rows `R3, RM1` and `R3, RM3`? And what if only one of those values exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no exact operator for this, you need to apply further logic, and this depends on your exact needs which isn't clear. The term for the problem at hand is [Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). One way is to exclude Rooms where there are other room members:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #T AS t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    #T AS t2
            WHERE   t2.RoomId = t.RoomId
            AND     t2.RoomMemberId NOT IN ('RM1', 'RM3')
        );
```

So in this both `R1` and `R2` would return records in the not exists subquery, so these would be excluded leaving only `R3`.

Alternatively if you just want the `RoomId` then you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  RoomId
FROM    #T
GROUP BY RoomId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN RoomMemberId IN ('RM1', 'RM3') THEN 1 END) = COUNT(1);
```

The test table and data I used for this is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T (RoomId VARCHAR(2), RoomMemberId VARCHAR(3));
INSERT #T (RoomId, RoomMemberId)
VALUES
    ('R1', 'RM1'), ('R1', 'RM2'), ('R1', 'RM3'), ('R2', 'Rm1'),
    ('R2', 'RM2'), ('R3', 'RM1'), ('R3', 'RM3');
```

Both of these examples work on the logic that the given room must only have members `RM1` or `RM3`, they do not specify they must have **both**. If you need this then you would need:

```
SELECT  RoomId
FROM    #T
GROUP BY RoomId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN RoomMemberId IN ('RM1', 'RM3') THEN 1 END) = COUNT(1) 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT RoomMemberId) = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from RoomMemberTable where RoomMemberId IN ('RM1','RM3')
```

Comment: no it wont work in this case. The IN operator works on OR condition i need something which works on AND condition. I mean here to get only those Rooms which contains only two RoomMembers 'RM1' and 'RM3'. If any Other member also availible with these RoomMembers than i dont need that record.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use OR operator........

```
Select * from RoomMemberTable where RoomMemberId ='RM1' Or RoomMemberId ='RM3'.
```

Use In only when there are more than two values,I prefer OR in this case rather than IN

**IN**:Range of values

**OR**:Either in One or Other